# my own subclass's delegate methods wrapping around UITextField's delegate methods is crashing my app

Tags: objective-c

I am creating my own subclass which is basically a subclass of `UIView` with a `UILabel` and a `UITextField` in it.

So I still want the delegate methods of `UITextField` to function, so I created my own protocol called `MyLabeledInputViewDelegate` which basically wraps around `UITextField`'s delegate methods in this way:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return [self.delegate inputViewShouldReturn:self];
}
```

And I since the textField is a property of an instance of my own class, I of course set it's delegate like this:

```
if (self.delegate) self.textField.delegate = self;
```

But however, it seems that if I init `MyLabeledInputView` with delegate set to `nil`, this crashes immediately for some reason.

Am I setting this up correctly or is there something that I am missing? Thank you very much!

My designated initializer is this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
      titleRelativeLength:(float)length
      titleText:(NSString *)text
      titleBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)color
      titleTextColor:(UIColor *)textColor
      textFieldBGColor:(UIColor *)textFieldBGColor
      textFieldTextColor:(UIColor *)textFieldTextColor
      delegate:(id<WRLabeledInputViewDelegate>)delegate;
```

the implementation is this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame titleRelativeLength:(float)length titleText:(NSString *)text titleBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)color titleTextColor:(UIColor *)textColor textFieldBGColor:(UIColor *)textFieldBGColor textFieldTextColor:(UIColor *)textFieldTextColor
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.titleRelativeLength = length;
        self.title = text;
        self.titleBackgroundColor = color;
        self.titleTextColor = textColor;
        self.textFieldBackgroundColor = textFieldBGColor;
        self.textFieldTextColor = textFieldTextColor;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Which basically only captures the passed in properties, and then I set the delegate of the UITextField in `layoutSubviews` to be the instance of my own class.

Comment: What is the console output?

Comment: it crashes on my designated initializer, and saying unrecognized selector send to some instance with it's memory address

Comment: What is the name of the selector and what is the class of the instance. This is how you narrow down the crash. It's telling you that the object you're sending messages to do not implement them

Comment: name of the selector is `initWithFrame:titleRelativeLength:titleText:titleBackgroundColor:titleTextColor:textFieldBGColor:textFieldTextColor:delegate:` which is the initializer.

Comment: Actually I think I'll just take Jsdodgers approach, this way I get the native delegate methods from UITextFields directly without having to worry about this. Thank you for your help though! I guess setting up delegates in my way isn't the recommended practice?

Comment: Alright. So which class are you sending that message to?

Comment: the class is `MyLabeledInputView`

Comment: I do it all the time, wrapping delegate methods and incorporating my own protocol. Your custom LabelView class is the delegate of the textField, isn't it? And then you're wrapping some of those methods to a different delegating object?

Comment: Ok, copy and paste the header and the init block of your custom class

Comment: I'll put it in the question to avoid clogging up comments.

Comment: Oh I was stupid enough to not put the delegate in the implementation... that's the problem :/ Thanks for your help!

Comment: On wrapping delegates, take for instance the Dropbox SDK. Sometimes I want a specialized class that handles one kind of upload. I'll make a wrapper class, wrap the delegate methods in it, and create a specialized protocol like "dropboxShare:didUploadSaveData:" so I don't have to do a bunch of if() blocks in one class to determine what object I am receiving in the delegate callbacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see now, you missed adding a parameter to your implementation. Add that and you'll be good to go. And `self.delegate = delegate;`

EDIT:

You should be doing this on any wrapped delegate calls, (or any time you create your own protocol)

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(inputViewShouldReturn:)]) {
    [self.delegate inputShouldReturn:self];
}
```

If you don't implement that delegate method in your listening class, you will get a crash unless you ask the object if it responds first.

Comment: Thanks! Accepted for earnest help :)

Comment: Yea, there's no reason why your program should immediately crash because you are trying to wrap delegate messages. As soon as you said the console error I knew it was something else

Comment: Also, set your textField delegate in your init method to self. Capture the methods you want to listen for in your class. Forward them with your protocol inside. Look at my new edit for more info:

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying some weird things when setting the delegate that are causing it to crash because you are trying to call methods on the wrong object. Most of the time when you call a method on a nil object, it just returns nil, but in cases such as this (I believe it is when the pointer thinks it is pointing to something, but it's actually pointing to the wrong type of object), it will give you the error that you are receiving.

I would suggest that instead of doing it this way, you override your setter and getter of your delegate in your subclass to set the textField's delegate instead, such as:

```
- (void)setDelegate:(id<UITextFieldDelegate>)delegate {
    self.textField.delegate = delegate;
}

- (id<UITextFieldDelegate>)delegate {
    return self.textField.delegate;
}
```

This way, you do not have to worry about handling the delegates in your subclass or dealing with them at all aside from these two methods; they will all automatically be handeld by the textField and the delegate.

Comment: That's actually a much better idea! Thanks!

Comment: In his context, if @Enzo does this, it won't work like he expects. Since he's wrapping delegate methods, he wants `SOME_OTHER_CLASS` to adhere to his custom protocol. Setting that delegate your way will set his textField to `SOME_OTHER_CLASS` and he actually wants his custom view class to be the textField delegate. Do you get what I mean